# Flatbar shifters for 11-speed GRX groupsets

Tags: shifter, compatibility, grx

I have a GRX RD-RX810 rear derailleur and I need a compatible (thumb) shift lever for flat bars.

Any suggestions which shifters are compatible for my setup?

Comment: I'm amazed that this isn't a duplicate, as GRX is basically a wide-ratio road drivetrain, and Shimano road and MTB 11 speed kit isn't directly compatible.  While I think that's been discussed here before, I can find it.

Comment: Yo puedo leer un poco español, pero esta pregunta no es muy facile para un novicio. ¿Timón = manillar?

Comment: @ChrisH What about these? Looks like 105/11-speed-compatible thumb shifters, should have GRX-compatible pull-ration, or am I wrong?: [link](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/105-5800/SL-RS700.html)

Comment: @DoNuT good find.  I think they ought to work.  I haven't worked with GRX (my gravel bike is 105 2×11) and I stopped thinking much about drivetrain compatibility between road and MTB series when I bought that bike - it's through-axle and my other bikes are QR.

Comment: @DoNuT That works: https://www.cube.eu/ch-en/cube-nulane-race-fe-rubyred-n-black/cb9372bb50c65be2c045a3ed7996cbb7

Comment: @Renaud Thanks, I'll put it as an answer and translate/update the question/tags when I'm back from office. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The other answer has already a specific product, but i wanted to answer in a more generic way for people with a similiar issue and maybe not the exact same product :)

You can find official compabilitly list of all shimano components at

https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/

You need to know which specific version you have. (not just RX810, but also 1x11/2x11 etc.)

In the compability chart, look for Shifters with the SL prefix.

SL = flat handlebar shifters

ST = drop handlebar shifters

For your case, you most likely you can use shifters from the 105 series and there was a limited edtion GRX specific flat handlebar shifters.

Comment: I didn't want to do product recommendation (since SL-U5000-R seems to be the other option if you ignore TT bike bar-end shifters) but yours is probably the better overall answer. It would be great if deep-linking into the compatibility chart would work.

Answer (score 3):

Shimano offers thumb shifters that are compatible with 11-speed road groupsets

https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/105-5800/SL-RS700.html

I haven't checked if there is a newer iteration of the product since 105 R5800 is out for a few years but they've been used on flatbar GRX bikes, as an example: https://www.cube.eu/ch-en/cube-nulane-race-fe-rubyred-n-black/cb9372bb50c65be2c045a3ed7996cbb7

**Edit** As out also mentioned in the other [answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/91461/69562), scrolling to the 11-speed section of the [road rear drivetrain compatibility chart](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/com?cid=C-453&acid=C-454) lists these (and SL-U5000-R) as the current options. **SL**-prefixed components is what you have to generally look for. ;)